# How to configure a keystore with trusted certificates for jenkins pod slaves created by Jenkins Kubernetes Plugin SunCertPathBuilderException

Tags: maven, jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins Kubernetes plugin to provision slave agents (pods) that run the different tasks of a Java project build pipeline.

One of the pipeline stages consists of using Sonarqube to analyze the Java code:

```
try {
    withSonarQubeEnv('SONARQUBE_CFG') {
        sh "./mvnw org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar -Dsonar.branch=$branch -Dsonar.verbose=true"
    }
} catch (ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace()
}
```

The problem is I'm getting a SunCertPathBuilderException because it can't validate the certificate chain.

```
[ERROR] SonarQube server [https://sonarqube.profile.es] can not be reached
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 19.894 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-11T16:45:10Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project myproject: Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail to download libraries from server: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
```

I have mounted the keystore from a config map in the jenkins slave pod at `/cfg/keystore.jks` path but can't come up with a way to enforce the usage of that keystore. Ideas?

Comment: I have the same problem. I put cert to JDK cacert and i have jenkins restarted

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not a certificate error.
Your server simply cannot be reached.

- Is it on?
- Can you ping it from your jenkins server/pod?
- Is the necessary port opened for Jenkins to reach it?  (gotta google this)